# Array Object to string conversion using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have code like this in my Laravel project

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "value 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "value 2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "value 3"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "value 4"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "value 5"
    }
]
```

and i want to get like this

```
$output = "value 1,value 2,value 3,value 4,value 5";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what have you tried so far?

Comment: '"' . implode (",", array_pluck($data, 'name')) . '"' and see laravel helpers function https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all you need to assign it to a variable, then

```
$output='';
foreach($varaible ad $var){
 if(!$loop->last){
   $output.=$var->name.',';
 }else{
   $output.=$var->name;
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... where does this `$loop` variable come from?